# #warning directive in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, preprocessor, compiler-directives

I know the #warning directive does not exist in vb.net... is there anything like it?
I want to be able to throw messages (warnings) at compiler time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I've ever been able to find... no.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same as preprocessor warning, but in the most cases where I need a warning for the user I generate one using the ObsoleteAttribute:

`<ObsoleteAttribute("You should no used this method!", False)>
Sub MySub()
End Sub`

However, since it is not the same as a preprocessor warning it will only trigger if someone uses the methode.