# Alternative for #Warning directive im Visual Basic (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, warnings, deprecated, directive

As no `#warning` [directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx) exists in Visual Basic like in [c#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963th5x3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#)

Is there any way to bring a message at compile time?

Regards.

*PS: This question is not a duplicate of [#warning directive in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192822/warning-directive-in-vb-net), I want here to discuss about alternative.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#warning directive in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192822/warning-directive-in-vb-net)

Comment: No, list of all directives https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx, you can however still do something like TODO list (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979080.aspx - on german only)